# Maximum principle application

Tags: complex-analysis, maxima-minima, maximum-principle

Assume $f(z)=\dfrac{z^2}{z+2}.$ I want to find: $$\begin{equation}
\max_{|z|\leq1}\bigg|\frac{z^2}{z+2}\bigg|
\end{equation}$$

Taking the **maximum principle** into consideration, it must be true that: $$|z|=1\iff z=e^{i\phi}.$$ Thus: $$ \big|f(z)\big|=\bigg|\frac{e^{2i\phi}}{e^{i\phi}+2}\bigg|=\frac{\big|e^{2i\phi}\big|}{\big|e^{i\phi}+2\big|}=\frac{1}{\big|e^{i\phi}+2\big|}$$

From there, I don't get how to determine the upper bound of the modulus of $f$ to find the maximum. Also, at which points does it occur?

Comment: $|e^{i\phi} + 2|$ is the distance between $z = e^{i\phi}$ to the point $-2$ . To get the maximum of $|f(z)|$, you evaluate it at the point on unit circle closest to $-2$.

Comment: @achillehui that's more eloquently put

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that$$\bigl|f(z)\bigr|=\frac1{\sqrt{\bigl(\cos(\phi)+2\bigr)^2+\bigl(\sin(\phi)\bigr)^2}}=\frac1{\sqrt{5+4\cos(\phi)}}.$$It is clear that the maximum is $1$, attained when $\phi=\pi$.

Comment: Thank you! I believe $(\sin(\phi))^2$ is only squared one time, isn't it?

Comment: @Andrewtz98 Yes. I will edit my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$2+e^{i\phi} $ is $(x-2)^2+ y^2=1$ so that $|(x,y)|\geq |(1,0)|=1$